# How to use _Pragma operator in macro?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, gcc-warning

I'm trying to use the _Pragma operator in order to ignore a warning inside a macro:

```
#define RAII_BLOCK() \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push \"-Wshadow\"") \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wshadow\"") \
    auto a = RAII(); \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")

void foo() {
    RAII_BLOCK();
    {
        RAII_BLOCK();    
    }
}
```

But I see really odd behavior from gcc. If `RAII_BLOCK` is a macro with no arguments it works as expected: https://godbolt.org/g/J6RxDV

But if I add the parenthesis (in my use case I actually need to pass a real argument), gcc starts complaining: https://godbolt.org/g/tbNtje

Note that clang works as expected in both cases. Does anyone know how to get around this issue (while keeping the shadow warnings for the rest of the code)?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53469 and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=715271, it seems that GCC's handling of `_Pragma` diagnostic directives in macro invocations had a few issues in the past, possibly still.

I would suggest another route, which is to entirely avoid having to override diagnostics settings in the RAII_BLOCK definition:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct RAII{
    RAII() { cout << "acquired" << endl; }
    ~RAII() { cout << "released" << endl; }
};

#define CONCAT_(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_(a, b)
#define RAII_BLOCK() auto CONCAT(a,__COUNTER__) = RAII();

void foo() {
    RAII_BLOCK();
    {
        RAII_BLOCK();
    }
}
```

This way, all your scope guard variable names will always be unique, removing the necessity for protecting yourself from shadow definitions.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas I also considered this option, but unfortunately this workaround doesn't work for me as I need to refer to the variable by name later in the block. I ended up just having the user of RAII_BLOCK define the variable. Meaning the user would need to do `auto tmp = RAII_BLOCK();` which is a more accepted idiom in C++.